# Output of creating a new variable of two properties over one another?

Tags: javascript, variables, properties

I've been trying to make a very simple and basic game to improve my JavaScript skills. However, I've been having a problem with trying to have a 'ratio' that displays the health of a objects. Here's a similar code because the original code is too long:

```
function Person(health) {
    this.initialHealth = health;
    this.lostHealth = health;
}

var bob = new Person(100);
var enemy = new Person(100);

var bobAttack = function() {
    enemy.lostHealth = enemy.lostHealth - 50;  
};

var enemyHealth = enemy.lostHealth + '/' + enemy.initialHealth;

bobAttack();

console.log(enemyHealth);
```

The output is:`100/100` while I want it to be for example `50/100`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably expect 'lazy' evaluation, but you get the value of the expression immediately. That is, the expression `var enemyHealth = enemy.lostHealth + '/' + enemy.initialHealth` is fully evaluated before the `enemy.lostHealth` is changed, i.e. before the function `bobAttack()` is called. If you want delayed evaluation then you could use:

```
var enemyHealth = function() { 
    return enemy.lostHealth + '/' + enemy.initialHealth;
}

bobAttack();

console.log(enemyHealth());
```

Comment: Oh and just to clarify, the `return` statement will evaluate 'x' when the function is called but will already be evaluated if there is no return statement?

Comment: Don't quite get the question... the return value is evaluated when the function is called.. the return statement must be there, you can't omit it, if you want a function to return a result.